# Avoid repeat calling simulation/function with same arguments

Tags: matlab, simulation

This is a general algorithm question, but my primary environment is Matlab.

I have a function

out=f(arg1,arg2,,.....)

which takes a long time to execute and is expensive to compute (i.e. cluster time). A given argument argn can be a string, integer, vector, and even a function handle

For this reason, I want to avoid calling f(args) for the same argument values. Inside my program, this can occur in ways that are not necessarily controllable by the programmer.

So, I want to call f() once for each possible value of args, and save the results to disk. Then, whenever it is called the next time, check if there is currently a result for those argument values. If so, I would load it from disk.

My current idea is to create a cell variable, with one row for each function call. In the first column is out. In column 2:N are the values of argn, and check the equivalence of each individually.

Since the variable types of the arguments vary, how would I go about doing this?

Is there a better algorithm?

More generally, how do people deal with saving simulation results to disk and storing metadata? (other than cramming everything into a filename!)

Comment: In one word you are trying to implement memoization.

Comment: Thanks. One keyword helped my search immensely!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a function that looks something like this:

```
function result = myfun(input)

persistent cache

if isempty(cache)
    cachedInputs  = [];
    cachedOutputs = [];
    cache = {cachedInputs, cachedOutputs};
end

[isCached, idx] = ismember(input, cache{1});

if isCached
    result = cache{2}(idx);
else
    result = doHardThingOnCluster(input);
    cache{1}(end+1) = input;
    cache{2}(end+1) = result;
end
```

This simple example assumes that your inputs and outputs are both scalar numbers that can be stored in an array. If you have to deal with strings, or anything more complicated, you could use a cell array for caching rather than an array. Or in fact, maybe a `containers.Map` might be even better. Alternatively, if you have to cache really massive results, you might be better off saving it to a file and caching the file name, then loading the file in if you find it's been cached.

Hope that helps!